# How to create a database table if the fields are declared at run time?

Tags: qt, qsqlquery, qsqltablemodel, qsqldatabase

When creating table at run time using `qsqlquery` the fields of the `sqlite` database table are declared by user, and using that I want to create a table at run time.
How can I do that in `qsql` cpp?

```
qsqlQuery qry;
qry.exec("CREATE TABLE xyz ....."); // ???
```

Is there a way to create database Table using models like `qsqlTableModel`?

Comment: `qry.exec("CREATE TABLE xyz .....");` would be the method I have used to have `c++` code dynamically create a sqlite table.

Comment: ***Is there a way to create database Table using models like qsqlTableModel?*** I am pretty sure the answer is no. `QSqlTableModel` is for querying an existing table not for creating or altering a tables schema.

Comment: But how should I write query if columns are not known? are you saying I should append column names to a QString and then use `qry.exec(str);`

Comment: ***are you saying I should append column names to a QString and then use qry.exec(str);*** Yes you can dynamically create a string in your function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A code from my project. Just copied and pasted as is, but I think it should be enough for you to understand how to achieve your goal.

```
bool SqlTableManager::createTable()
{   
    QString qs = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ";
    qs += m_tableName + " (";

    bool firstElem = true;

    QString primaryKeys;

    for (auto &&item : m_columns)
    {
        if (!firstElem)
            qs += ", ";
        firstElem = false;
        qs += item.name + " " + item.type;
        if (item.primary)
        {
            if (!primaryKeys.isEmpty())
                primaryKeys += ", ";
            primaryKeys += item.name;
        }
    }

    if (!primaryKeys.isEmpty())
    {
        qs += ", PRIMARY KEY (";
        qs += primaryKeys;
        qs += ")";
    }

    qs += ")";
   
    auto [q,r] = m_db->createQuery(qs);
    if (!r || !q.exec())
    {
        setLastError(q.lastError());
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        clearLastError();
        return true;
    }
}
```